# What movie or TV show had a team of women preparing for battle while "smoking"?

Tags: story-identification, movie, tv

The movie/show I'm trying to ID is probably from the mid-90's to about 2008, and was in English. I can only remember one scene. In this scene there were about 10, give or take, beautiful women who appeared to be in a space ship (or maybe in a underground tunnel) and they looked like they were preparing for battle. They were dressed mostly in black tight-fitting uniforms.

The really odd thing was they all were smoking cigarettes. I can't remember if they had to smoke or if they called it something else.

I saw this movie/TV show around 2010. I couldn't find the name then. It is driving me nuts trying to ID this movie.

I've asked this question on other websites and got some suggestions: *Millennium*, *Screamers* and *The Invaders* 1995 made-for-TV mini-series. I haven't seen The Invaders but from what I've read about it, it doesn't sound like it. I've seen the other two and they definitely were not the movie I'm looking for.

I might be off on the time period it was made. It could be from the 80's because to the best of my recollection they had 80's-style big hair. Also, even though they were smoking cigarettes, it seems like they called them something other than cigarettes and they had to smoke for energy.

It's all a little fuzzy to me, so I might be off on some of the details. I'm sure it was sci-fi or futuristic fantasy. I'm also sure of multiple beautiful women smoking.  If anybody has any idea, even if you're unsure, let me know. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Women smoking in a an underground tunnel **or** on a spaceship in a movie from between *1980 and 2008*? That's not much to go on. Good luck.

Comment: Anything else you can tell us? Was the movie in English? Were the women all blond, brunettes, mixture? All the same race or mixture, etc. Any additional details can help eliminate or narrow down to get your answer.

Comment: It was in English. There was mixture of blondes and brunettes and I think they mostly white.

Comment: This wiki-list of SF tv movies might help: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_science_fiction_television_films#1990s

Comment: Not a great question, but this isn't a reason to give bad answers. Either there's such a scene or there isn't... hint: **if you don't remember this scene, refrain from answering.**

Comment: @Bob, are you SURE this wasn't a scene from Millenium (1989)? The scene where Louise and her team is preparing to go through the portal matches your description pretty closely. The team - all attractive women - are wearing dark gray jumpsuits, heavily addicted to smoking, and have big 80's style hair.

Answer (score 4):

I think the show you're describing is [Cleopatra 2525](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleopatra_2525).  It was filled with scantily dressed young women that lived underground, but in the future.

Comment: Welcome Martha - you can edit your original post. You can also add a link to [Cleopatra 2525](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cleopatra_2525) and clarify why you think this answers the question.

Answer (score -3):

is it possible you are thinking of Firefly that sounds like the start of the first episode to me. I hope this is the correct series.

Comment: I really can't remember that any female in this series have ever smoked. Though it rocks.

Comment: From what I remember of the first episode of Firefly, it starts in a trench during a war. One woman is present, Zoe, and she isn’t smoking.

Comment: There's no smoking in Firefly.

Comment: but there is a Gina Torres in both Firefly (Zoe) and Cleopatra 2525...